# JPA QueryDsl Group By NVL

Tags: jpa, querydsl

I want to group by nvl.

```
@Formula("NVL(COLUMN1,'N')")
@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
private String column1;
```

Are there any other methods other than the above method, JPQL, and NativeQuery?

**Example.**

> select
> nvl(column1, 'N'),
> sum(column2)
> from tbl
> group by nvl(column1, 'N')

Failed Item #1

```
jpaQueryFactory
    .select(
        tbl.column1.coalesce("N").as("column1"),
        tbl.column2.sum().as("column2")
    )
    .from(tbl)
    .groupBy(tbl.column1.coalesce("N").as("column1"))
    .fetch();
```

Failed Item #2

```
jpaQueryFactory
    .select(
        tbl.column1.coalesce("N").as("column1"),
        tbl.column2.sum().as("column2")
     )
    .from(tbl)
    .groupBy(tbl.column1.coalesce("N"))
    .fetch();
```